# CKAN schema.xml file break jetty/solr installation

Tags: solr, jetty, ckan

Before 17 december  I have installed **correctly** CKAN in UBUNTU 12.04. I have seen changes in 2.2 version.

In https://github.com/okfn/ckan there has been some changes.

Now after a couple of days trying to install in ubuntu 12.04 again (another machine) I'm facing a problem once I change schema.xml for jetty/solr.

Once installed jetty/solr I follow the instructions in:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-source.html

**127.0.01:8983/jetty/solr works ok before change schema.xml**

and in point 5.2, once I change original schema.xml from solr and I use ckan schema.xml and I  get error:

This is the command (copy/paste in terminal)
sudo mv /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml.bak

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/solr/schema.xml /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml

**ERROR:**
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Severe errors in solr configuration.
```

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

false

in null

---

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'schema.xml' in classpath or '/usr/share/solr/conf/', cwd=/var/cache/jetty/tmp
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openSchema(SolrResourceLoader.java:222)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.(IndexSchema.java:94)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:521)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
Powered by Jetty://

Here is the log out:

> 452 [main] INFO org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.24 551 [main] INFO
>   org.mortbay.log - Deploy /etc/jetty/contexts/javadoc.xml ->
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@351563ff{/javadoc,file:/usr/share/jetty/javadoc}
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/share/solr/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: No
>   /solr/home in JNDI 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: using
>   system property solr.solr.home: /usr/share/solr 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  INFO: Solr home set to
>   '/usr/share/solr/' 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init INFO:
>   SolrDispatchFilter.init() 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: No
>   /solr/home in JNDI 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: using
>   system property solr.solr.home: /usr/share/solr 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer initialize INFO:
>   looking for solr.xml: /usr/share/solr/solr.xml 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  INFO: Solr home set to
>   '/usr/share/solr/' [Fatal Error] :2:6: The processing instruction
>   target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log GRAVE: Exception during
>   parsing file: solrconfig.xml:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target
>   matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:110)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:130)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)  at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:30)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
>
> 04-ene-2014 10:59:22 org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
>   GRAVE: Could not start SOLR. Check solr/home property
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:110)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:130)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)  at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:30)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
>   04-ene-2014 10:59:22 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log GRAVE:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:110)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:130)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)  at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:30)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
>
> 04-ene-2014 10:59:22 org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
>   INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() done 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet init INFO: SolrServlet.init()
>   04-ene-2014 10:59:22 org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
>   locateSolrHome INFO: No /solr/home in JNDI 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: using
>   system property solr.solr.home: /usr/share/solr 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet init INFO: SolrServlet.init() done
>   04-ene-2014 10:59:22 org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
>   locateSolrHome INFO: No /solr/home in JNDI 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome INFO: using
>   system property solr.solr.home: /usr/share/solr 04-ene-2014 10:59:22
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrUpdateServlet init INFO:
>   SolrUpdateServlet.init() done 1147 [main] INFO org.mortbay.log -
>   Opened /var/log/jetty/2014_01_04.request.log 1176 [main] INFO
>   org.mortbay.log - Started SelectChannelConnector@:8983

Answer (score 1):

Solr can't find your solr.xml file at `/etc/solr/conf/schema.xml`. Check that this file exists in this location. If the file is a symlink, check that it links to the right file. Symlink or not, check that the Solr user has permission to read the file.

Comment: I have ckeched my /etc/solr/conf/ and I have: schema.xml -> /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/solr/schema-2.0.xml, do I need the original file or with the symlink is enough???

Comment: Try copying the file rather than symlinking it, there's less that can go wrong that way.

Comment: Hi. I did that but no way.

Installed fresh new copy using package option ( not valid in production for me right now) and everything works great.

Compared two files and are exactly the same.

Always fails in that point.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

delete the symbolic link in /usr/share/solr/conf and copy your schema.xml file to /usr/share/solr/conf directory, and try again